# Mascara Jquery em campos criados dinamicamente

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho uma página de cadastro de valores de produtos, onde tenho um campo input com mascara de valor em R$. Mas como esse campo é criado dinamicamente após uma busca no bd, a mascara entá funcionando apenas no primeiro input. Sei de uma solução mas ela não fica amigavel além de deixar a página lenta. Queria uma solução pratica e viável. Segue o codígo.

HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
    echo "<div class='produtos'>
        <div style='float:left;'><img src=".base_url()."uploads/produtos/".$produto->foto." title=".$produto->nome."></div>
                <div class='descricao_produto'>
                    <font size='4'>".$produto->nome."</font><br>
                    <font size='2'>".$produto->descricao."</font><br>
                    <input type='text' name='preco_produto' style='width:60px;' value='' placeholder='Preço' id='preco'>
                </div>
            </div>";
} ?>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#preco").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', 
   showSymbol:true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', symbolStay: true});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma grande falha que você está comentendo é colocar o mesmo *id* em vários elementos com este `foreach()` no seu [php](/questions/tagged/php), o ideal é que você substitua por uma classe.

### Php

```
<?php foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
    echo "<div class='produtos'>
        <div style='float:left;'><img src=".base_url()."uploads/produtos/".$produto->foto." title=".$produto->nome."></div>
                <div class='descricao_produto'>
                    <font size='4'>".$produto->nome."</font><br>
                    <font size='2'>".$produto->descricao."</font><br>
                    <input type='text' name='preco_produto' style='width:60px;' value='' placeholder='Preço' class='preco'>
                </div>
            </div>";
} ?>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".preco").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', showSymbol:true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', symbolStay: true});
});
```

Você pode conferir o resultado neste [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Xm8/)

Answer (score 4):

Ao invés de usar o id '#preco', experimente usar uma classe, '.preco' , por exemplo.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$(".preco").maskMoney({symbol:'R$ ', ...
```